# How do I make the entire UIView fade to white and back?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, fadein, fadeout

This question is solved already.

I am trying to make the screen fade to white and back when a button is pressed. I have found some code that fades the view's alpha to 0 and back to 1, which changes the entire screen's color to black. What I want is a way to make it fade to white instead of black. I am a beginner at coding and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code for the extension that fades the UIView:

```
extension UIView {
func fadeIn(_ duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)  }

func fadeOut(_ duration: TimeInterval = 1.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: completion)
}
```

Here is my code for the implementation of the extension:

```
@IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.view.fadeOut(completion: {
        (finished: Bool) -> Void in
        self.view.fadeIn()
    })
}
```

Comment: If you have a white superview and fade the alpha of the subview, it will fade to white.

Comment: I am a beginner so could you possibly explain how to do that? Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Think about what he said. If there is a white view behind you and you fade to zero alpha, what will the user see? White.

Comment: I get that, its just that I don't know how to fade the alpha of the subview instead of the view.

Comment: I figured out how to fade the subview finally. @Paulw11 thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please either delete the question or give the answer as an answer. Do not write SOLVED in the title.

Comment: Apologies for the ridiculous question. I was self teaching myself coding at the time, and I had no idea what I was doing. I was going to delete the question now, but I guess it could be useful to other complete beginners so I will leave it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let whiteView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
whiteView.backgroundColor = .white
whiteView.alpha = 0
view.addSubview(whiteView)

UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
  whiteView.alpha = 1.0
}, completion: nil)
```